# How do I use the full editor screen in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

I know it must be a dumb question, but Android Studio has so many options that confuses me. I want to use the whole editor section and not the half as shown in the following link.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4IYln.png

I'm new into this and willing to learn Flutter. Thank you! ^^

Comment: You appear to be using the "whole editor section". Your lines happen to be short and do not extend into the right side of the editor window.

Comment: lol I'm dumb, thank you CommonsWare

Comment: Just ignore the imaginary line at 80 chars; unless you share code with 640x480 pixel screens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the value for `Hard wrap at` in the Android Studio Preferences to a value higher than 80. But even very high values won't let you use the full width of your editor for the sake of common Flutter code style. If a line gets too long, you might want to consider breaking it apart to make it easier to read and understand. Or, regarding Flutter, flatten the widget nesting by extracting parts to custom widgets.

You could also use the remaining space to display the file explorer or to view two files side by side.

[image: Android Studio Preferences]

Comment: Thank you for your tips! Those are very useful ^^

Comment: Glad it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

You are using the whole editor section. That's a hypothetical line that is adviced to keep your codes on left side of it.